ошибка в OrangeFox: Unable To find partition for path /system_root устройство: Topaz (Xiaomi) с динамическими разделами A/B
случилось это после того как я:

прошил AfterLife Project By superxorn
у меня отвалился тач скрин в Recovery
я прошил Xiaomi.eu после чего поверх него прошил Paranoid Android
аптейтер "п+одхватил" прошивку как своё обновление после чего выдал ошибку Failed to mount /System, /system_dklm, /vendor, /vendor_dklm
я не обратив внимание начал прошивать сток Hyper OS
после этого рекавери выдал эту ошибку и слот B "сломался" а раздел сам System_B больше просто не существует Туда нельзя просто зашить систему. Дайте пожалуста подробный туториал как вернуть стоковую разметку разделов

